# Referencing Xamarin Application Resources from Code

Tags: xamarin, colors, resources, keynotfoundexception

I have an app.xaml that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Foo.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <!-- Application resource dictionary -->
        <Color x:Key="MyRed">#ad1929</Color>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

If I try to reference one of my colours like so:

```
var myRed = (Color)Application.Current.Resources["MyRed"];
```

I get an exception:

`System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The resource 'MyRed' is not present in the dictionary.`

Is it something to do with trying to reference the resource from a different project?

Can't work out where I'm going wrong...

Comment: It works on my side. You could delete the folder `bin` and `obj` , then clean and rebuild your project .

Comment: No joy, unfortunately.

Comment: You could share your sample so that I can test it on my side .